# Does the set intersection operation has unit

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

I'm trying to get better understanding of binary operations, and I came across this problem: namely on one online discussions I saw that set intersection as binary operation doesn't have a unit, however I think it has:

The set intersection operation for any set universe $U$ is defined on the $\mathcal P(U) \times \mathcal P(U)$ set. From the definition of unit for binary operation, wouldn't it be true that the $U$ set is the unit of this operation. Any set in $PU$ intersected with $U$ will give back the set, and it works in both directions.

Am I doing something wrong, or the discussion on that place was wrong?

Comment: See [The fundamental properties of set algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_properties_of_set_algebra). You have to consider a "universe" that is a set (e.g. $\mathbb N$): the set used to define the complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your universe $U$ is *not* a set. You cannot intersect it with anything, and so your proof does not work (for this reason, it is also incorrect to write $\mathcal P(U)$, as the operator $\mathcal P$ - returning the set of all subsets of a given set - can only be applied to, well, sets themselves.

Hence, what was claimed in the other discussion is true: there exist no *set* $A$ such that for all sets $B$, $A \cap B = B$.

Edit: It is possible to consider some sort of set algebra, in which such things do make sense ($A \cap U = A$, and so on). This is however a choice that has to be made consciously; the typical ZF(C) axioms do not define those operations, and the "collection of all sets, $U$", is explicitly *not* a set on which you can perform those operations (power set, cardinality, intersection ...).

Answer (score 2):

For a given *set* $U$, the intersection indeed has $U$ as the identity element, *among the subsets of $U$*.

On the other hand, seeing the intersection as an operation on *all sets*, its identity element would be the *biggest set* (the union of all sets), and such a thing doesn't exist (at least it's not a set).